# How to get MYSQL dynamic query using stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I am trying to run the dynamic query using a stored procedure in which I am sending the where condition case for example.

My sample stored procedure is shown here:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Storedproc`(IN getwhereconditon varchar(1000))
    BEGIN
    set @param=getwhereconditon ;
    SET @S=concat('Select * from table where (1)',@param);
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    END
```

Here my stored procedure's name is `Storedproc` in which I am passing the where condition details and when I call my stored procedure I am getting this error

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0tablecol=1' at line

Comment: Show the real value you are passing.And what`s with the (1)?

Comment: @Mihai where(1) is the condition if none of the value of comes it will run without an error Storeproc(and nqh.nqh_quarry_id=2)

Comment: why are you using `and` in `Storeproc(and nqh.nqh_quarry_id=2)`

Comment: The error message doesnt seem to be for the parameter above.Also you shoud have quotes for your parameter.

Comment: there is problem in my SP which i Can't able to identify it and yes i am send the parameter in a quotes.If you got any better solution in my In case of my SP then help me out

Comment: @ashok_p watch my SP for example  set @param=and nqh.nqh_quarry_id=2 ;
    SET @S=concat('Select * from table where (1)',@param);

Comment: Leave a space after (1)

Comment: @Mihai i think that's not the solution for leaving the sapce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc(IN _where VARCHAR(512))
BEGIN
  SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM table1';
  IF COALESCE(_where, '') <> '' THEN
    SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql, ' WHERE ', _where);
  END IF;
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

or

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc(IN _where VARCHAR(512))
BEGIN
  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM table1', COALESCE(CONCAT(' WHERE ', NULLIF(_where, '')), ''));
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Sample usage:

```sql
CALL myproc(NULL);
CALL myproc('name=''John''');
CALL myproc('age > 25');
CALL myproc('age < 28 OR age > 30');
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c53503b/1)** demo